# Angular get height position on window scroll event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, dom-events

I'm getting the correct height position on browser console when I scroll, but I get an error on Angular development server console:

> "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'."

Also Visual Studio Code marks 'srcElement' and 'children'. I guess it's deprecated. How can I replace this?

```js
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  scrollFunction($event: Event){
    let scrollOffset = $event.srcElement.children[0].scrollTop;
    console.log("window scroll: ", scrollOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all you want to do is detect the position of the scroll.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
track(event) {
   console.debug("Scroll Event", window.pageYOffset );
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5LL9Dbp2Kw8SjGVl